# how to load one icon from a icon collection picture

Tags: html, css, asp.net, icons, styles

I am not very familiar with web front-end.

The web designer gave me JPG file it is a bar full of icons.

[image]

But what i need is to use these icons one by one.

I don't know if there is a easy way to load a single part from this big picture like:

```
load_part_from_picture (fileName,oneIconSize=80x80, index=1)
```

Or i just need to cut these icons into single ones.

My programming language is ASP.Net and C#

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul li {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAx.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: -60px 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: -180px 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: -240px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS class. This is a optimization technique called CSS sprites. See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj2n061L/)

```
.first-icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAx.png') 0 0;
}

.second-icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAx.png') 65px 0;
}

.third-icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAx.png') 125px 0;
}
```

Use like below in your HTML:

```
<div class="first-icon"></div>
<div class="second-icon"></div>
<div class="third-icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use one common class with separate class with sprite image

```
.icon{height:30px; float:left; margin-left:10px; width:30px; background:url("icon.jpg") no-repeat;}
.icon.home{background-position:0 0;}
.icon.services{background-position:-40px 0;}
.icon.product{background-position:-80px 0;}
.icon.about{background-position:-120px 0;}

<div class="icon home"></div>
<div class="icon services"></div>
<div class="icon product"></div>
<div class="icon about"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image given by your designer is called as image sprite.
An image sprite is a collection of images put into a single image.
Using image sprites will reduce the number of server requests and save bandwidth.

Now how you can use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#home {
    width: 65px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAx.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#next {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAx.png");
    background-position: 65px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="home" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_trans.gif"><br><br>
<img id="next" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_trans.gif">

</body>
</html>
```

> NOTE : In `<img>` tag the image used is 1px X 1px  (blank) image so you can see the
>   image clearly, otherwise the original image is overlap on it. This can
>   be done using `<div>` also, if you do not want to use `<img>`

Here is reference : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp